# Using について with しつもんする

Tags: grammar

In my japanese textbook, for the word しつもんする it has the note "(s.t.について)" where s.t. means something. I tried creating a sentence based off of this note and I want to know if it makes sense:

> 先生にしゅくだいについてしつもんしました。
>   I asked the teacher a question about the homework.

Comment: Please read the section "Alternative Websites for Translations **and Proofreading**" of this meta post: https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/11104

Comment: Are there any particular sticking points for you?  Proofreading on its own may be off topic, but if you feel like something is off, we can help clarify that sticking point.